# Programmatically determine SSL certificate's expiration date in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

How can I determine the expiration date of an SSL certificate using the `openssl` ruby library?

I read these [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Certificate.html). I see how to load the certificate. Just not sure how to determine the expiration date.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After loading, `cert.not_after` should be your certificate expiration date.

Comment: Just a note, testing this in a IRB session was incredibly useful for exploring the `x509` object. It is a great way to see what other data is available on the object.

Answer (score 0):

For the lazy (based on @joachim-isaksson s answer):

```rb
require 'openssl'

certificate_file = 'server/cert.pem'

cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new File.read(certificate_file)
puts cert.inspect

puts cert.not_after
```